# Remove several elements from Postgres array with jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to use jOOQ to create a function akin to [arrayRemove](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/util/postgres/PostgresDSL.html#arrayRemove-T:A-T-) but that allows removing several elements at once from a PostgreSQL column of type `uuid[]`.

So my first attempt was:

```
private Field<UUID[]> arrayRemoveAll(final Field<UUID[]> field, final Set<UUID> elements) {
    return select(field("array_agg(tab.col)", UUID[].class))
            .from(unnest(field).as("tab", "col"))
            .where(field("tab.col", UUID.class).notIn(elements))
            .asField();
}
```

Which succeeds at removing every requested element, but has the problem of returning `null` instead of an empty array if I attempt to remove every element.

So I added a coalesce to my code to make it return an empty array:

```
private Field<UUID[]> arrayRemoveAll(final Field<UUID[]> field, final Set<UUID> elements) {
    final Field<UUID[]> newArray = select(field("array_agg(tab.col)", UUID[].class))
            .from(unnest(field).as("tab", "col"))
            .where(field("tab.col", UUID.class).notIn(elements))
            .asField();
    return coalesce(newArray, field("{}", UUID[].class));
}
```

But running this code threw this exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [<<confidential SQL removed>>]
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
```

This is the part of the SQL exception it is complaining about (notice the trailing comma and missing 2nd parameter in the `coalesce`):

```
coalesce((select array_agg(tab.col)
          from unnest("my_schema"."my_table"."my_field") as "tab"("col")
          where tab.col not in (?, ?)), )
```

Is this a bug in jOOQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I had a mix of `field` and `val` in the code above, changing `field("{}", UUID[].class)` to `val(new UUID[0])` solves the problem.

Also check Lukas Eder's answer about how to solve the issue using `field`.

So the final code, with generics, looks like this:

```
private <T> Field<T[]> arrayRemoveAll(final Field<T[]> field, final Set<T> elements, final T[] emptyArray) {
    final Field<T[]> newArray = select(field("array_agg(tab.col)"))
            .from(unnest(field).as("tab", "col"))
            .where(field("tab.col").notIn(elements))
            .asField();
    return coalesce(newArray, val(emptyArray));
}
```

And you can use it in your statements like this:

```
using(configuration)
    .update(MY_TABLE)
    .set(MY_TABLE.MY_COLUMN,
         arrayRemoveAll(MY_TABLE.MY_COLUMN, someElements, new UUID[0]))
    .where(MY_TABLE.ID.eq(...))
    .execute();
```

Comment: Still not sure if using `field` should make jOOQ generate invalid SQL, but at least now I have a solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `field("{}")` does not generate the `{}` string in the SQL, but is considered a part of jOOQ's plain SQL templating language, which unfortunately doesn't allow for escaping those braces:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating

Luckily, PostgreSQL supports a more formal, standards-compliant way to create an empty array literal:

```java
field("array[]::uuid[]", UUID.class)
```